# how to check that file was opened successfully in two lines

Tags: perl

Sorry, but I can't find answer to this.

If I have the following line

```
my $FH;
open FH,"somefile";
```

Now I want to check if FH was opened successfully, but I would like to do this in different line, not using the or syntax.

I tried if ( $FH ), but it did not work for me.

thanks.

Comment: Unless `FH` is a typo: `open $FH` is probably what you are after. No sense declaring a lexical variable if you are going to use a global anyway.

Comment: By the way.. this seems like one of those cases where you are asking The Wrong Question. What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @TLP, `or` produces poor code if you want to do more than `die`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [`open`-Manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html):

> Open returns nonzero on success, the undefined value otherwise. If the
>   open involved a pipe, the return value happens to be the pid of the
>   subprocess.

So you could do something like that:

```
my $FH;
my $file_opened = open $FH, '<', 'somefile';

if($file_opened) {
    print "open";
    close($FH);
}
```

Or without the additional variable in one line:

```
if(open $FH, '<', 'somefile') {
    print "--open";
    close($FH);
}
```

Comment: @mob: you are right, thank you for the clarification. I edited my answer and quoted directly from the `open`-reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in one line:

```
open( my $FH, '<', 'somefile' ) or die "Could not open file: $!\n";
```

This gives you the advantage of printing out the reason that the file could not be opened.

**Edit:** If you want to do the same thing in two lines:

```
use autodie;
open( my $FH, '<', 'somefile' );
```

Comment: This is the idiomatic way to do it

Comment: But eran has specifically said that that is not what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't want to use the return value of `open`, the core module `Scalar::Util` provides the `openhandle` function that will tell you if a variable is a file handle that is ready to use.

```
use Scalar::Util 'openhandle';

open my $FH, '<', 'some_file.txt';

unless (openhandle $FH) {
    # handle error here
}
```